# Trouble passing search value into querystring url

Tags: javascript, input, query-string

I am working on an input box that is located on the homepage of my website to a map that is located within my site.  I want to allow the user to input their address on the homepage if they want and have whatever value they enter in pass through to the page where the map is.  I know you can have a form and an input box, but I haven't figured out how to pass in the value yet.  I've tested out putting the value in the action part of the form just to test that out and it's not working.  Here is the code that I currently have.  I need to pass the value from the input box to the part of the url after address.  I've tried putting in value and everything else and nothing works.  Thanks for any help!

```
form action="TestLocator2.aspx?address=">
 <input type="text" value="FIND A RETAILER" 
 onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='FIND A RETAILER';" 
 onfocus="if(this.value=='FIND A RETAILER')this.value='';"   /><input type="hidden" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input should have the `name` attribute set to whatever variable you want to receive either via `GET` or `POST` on your action script. The URL will encode itself based on the information you submit. This input:

```
<input name="address" type="text" … />
```

Will generate this URL when sent:

```
http://example.com/TestLocator2.aspx?address=Whatever+you+wrote+on+the+input
```

And you can retrieve its value like this:

```
$_POST['address'];
```

Or

```
$_GET['address'];
```

Note the the `GET` method won't generate a *visible* URL.

Comment: The Post query was exactly what I needed!!  Thanks for the info!!